# ServerSide Sorting control prevents retrieval of operational attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap

If I use a ServerSideSort control, the entries are sorted nicely for me, but I can't retrieve any operational attributes, even if I specifically request them, e.g. "entryUUID", or "+". If I remove the SSS control I get the operational attributes as I always did before. All I get are the ordinary attributes.

Is this a known feature of the SSS specification? or a known problem in OpenLDAP 2.4.30?

Comment: What is the result when the criticality field is set to `true`?

Comment: @TerryGardner It is set to true.

Comment: The server should return the operational attributes if the authentication state of the connection permits. If the criticality field is `true` and the server cannot return results for whatever reason (matching rule problem or the server is simply unwilling to perform the sort, for example) then the server must return `unavailableCriticalExtension`. Your example works on my server just fine, though it's not OpenLDAP. Are the attributes being used operational attributes?

Comment: @Terry I don't understand your last question.

Comment: Are the sort keys operational attributes?

Comment: @Terry Yes, I am sorting on entryUUID, in the process of sorting out another issue with corrupt entryUUIDs in OpenLDAP 2.4.26 or thereabouts, I have 81 entries withh entryUUID values in the range [0-9a-f], one digit only. So I was sorting on those trying to get those entries first, but as I couldn't get the actual value I can't tell where to stop.

Comment: Correction: a bug in OpenLDAP. Adversely voting on useful questions is merely site vandalism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition, and those described in your comments, sounds like a server software defect. An LDAP compliant server should either:

- return the entries with attribute as requested, *even if unsorted* (criticality `false`)
- return `unavailableCriticalExtension` *and no entries* (criticality `true`)

As for sorting on an operational attribute like `entryUUID`, several servers I tested refused to sort, but did return results (with criticality `false`).

Perhaps you could export the data to an LDIF file and deal with your entries with single digit `entryUUID`, and re-import the data.

Comment: Yes, I finally bit the bullet and did exactly that.

Comment: I reported this as a bug to userbooster.de and they have accepted it.

Comment: And fixed it in their release of OpenLDAP 2.4.34.